# jQuery fancybox iframe page change content to other page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Hi I'm creating form in Fancybox using iframe.

I want to use buttons on first popup to load different pages. Here is the code for button on current popup.

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.open({href : 'galeria_popup_form.html', title : 'My title'});">
<button class="cta_zaglosuj"></button></a>
```

I don't want to open iframe within iframe. I want current popup to change it's content to different html file.

Is it possible without browser understanding it as a Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL?

Answer (score 1):

You need smth like this? (You should know your iframe id or if it is only iframe, then just change #iframe_ID to iframe):

```
$('.cta_zaglosuj').click(function(){
    $("#iframe_ID").attr("src") = "http://google.com";
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, simple link is opening href in same window. Dumb question, dumb problem.

```
<a href="galeria_popup_form.html">
<button class="cta_zaglosuj"></button></a>
```